# Problem with ORs in JOIN statement

Tags: sql, performance, join

I have a problem with the SQL statement detailed below. The query returns the results I need, but takes an insane amount of time to execute. I now have so many records in the db that the page generally won't load.

```
SELECT dscan.guid, dscan.drive, dscan.folder, dscan.filename, source.guid  
FROM source 
RIGHT JOIN dscan ON (
  (source.guid & '_dtr' = dscan.guid OR source.guid & '_dto' = dscan.guid OR source.guid = dscan.guid)  
  AND dscan.guid LIKE '%" & Replace(strSearch_guid, "'", "''") & "%'  
  AND dscan.filename NOT LIKE '.[_]%'  
  AND dscan.drive = 'Z:')  
WHERE source.guid Is Null  
ORDER BY dscan.drive, dscan.guid
```

From what I've been able to find online, ORs in JOIN statements are a problem, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

I'm comparing database records against filenames to identify errors - but the filenames sometimes have '_dtr' or '_dto' appendages that I have to take into consideration.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the `OR`s?  If you reduce it to just one test does it run quickly?  Also: what indices are defined on these tables?

Comment: What database & version?

Comment: I'm positive the ORs are the problem. The SQL executes very quickly if I remove them.

source.guid is indexed but dscan.guid isn't (this table is subject to reasonably frequent mass-updates). I had tried indexing it, but it made no difference. From what I've read elsewhere, ORs in a join will cause indices to be ignored.

DB is MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I don't think that your performance issue comes from the "ORs" but mainly because you use to concatenate string with column values to make the join.

Also joining on string data does not give the best performance. On the other hand, If you columns were indexed (add an index on them) it would help (if you were not concatening string again)

As a solution, I don't know if it is possible or wanted to add columns to that table and include versions of the strings with the "extensions" already added, so the query would not need to concatenate them ?

Those are some work arounds, not the real solution

Comment: Adding a column to the dscan table is my backup option. A SQL solution will save me some hassles though.

Comment: Thanks to all who tried to help me with this one. I was hoping for a SQL magic bullet, but I don't think there is one. I've opted for adding a column to the dscan table which holds the '_dtr' and '_dto' data, which allows me to run the query with a straight source.guid = dscan.guid.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of constructed predicate comparsion values, and 'Like' with wildcrads at the beginning will require complete table scans. This will be a major performance hit for large tables until you redesign your schema to eliminate this.  However, You can eliminate the performance hit from ORs by unioning three separate sql statements instead.  try this:

```
    SELECT D.guid, D.drive, D.folder, D.filename, S.guid  
    FROM dscan D Left Join source S
        ON S.guid & '_dtr' = D.guid 
          AND D.guid LIKE '%" & Replace(strSearch_guid, "'", "''") & "%'   
          AND D.filename NOT LIKE '.[_]%'    
          AND D.drive = 'Z:')  
    WHERE S.guid Is Null  
  Union
    SELECT D.guid, D.drive, D.folder, D.filename, S.guid  
    FROM dscan D Left Join source S
        ON S.guid & '_dto' = D.guid  
          AND D.guid LIKE '%" & Replace(strSearch_guid, "'", "''") & "%'   
          AND D.filename NOT LIKE '.[_]%'    
          AND D.drive = 'Z:')  
    WHERE S.guid Is Null  
  Union
    SELECT D.guid, D.drive, D.folder, D.filename, S.guid  
    FROM dscan D Left Join source S
        ON S.guid = D.guid    
          AND D.guid LIKE '%" & Replace(strSearch_guid, "'", "''") & "%'   
          AND D.filename NOT LIKE '.[_]%'    
          AND D.drive = 'Z:')  
    WHERE S.guid Is Null  
    ORDER BY D.drive, D.guid
```

Comment: `union` kicks off a distinct. If these tables really are big, these will return a ton of results, and have to sort through and eliminate all of the repeated `null`s. I can't imagine that this would be faster on any level than doing an `in`, nor can SQL Server, which I've tested this before on.

Comment: I'd a union and come up with this query too as my best effort. The problem is that this query will return way too many records because for any given record, even if a match is found in one query (meaning it gets excluded because of the source.guid Is Null) it will necessarily get returned up by the other two queries because the dscan.guid can't concurrently = source.guid, source.guid &'_dto' and source.guid & '_dtr'

Comment: @Eric,  As Nick menmtions, Union kicks off a Distinct, so these duplicates should be excluded. If you see different behavior, then there are other columns in the output that are different.

@Nick,  in theory I agree with you, and I do not completely understand what the query processor does with a Union, but in practice (as I said) I Have seen this to produce better results than using ORs in a Where clause predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try dissecting it a bit with some parentheses.

((source.guid & '_dtr' = dscan.guid) OR (source.guid & '_dto' = dscan.guid) OR (source.guid = dscan.guid))

Comment: Out of sheer desperation I played around with parentheses like this and it made no difference. The problem is the ORs which, as Charles Bretana says, force table scans.

Answer (score 0):

`or`s are notorious performance suckers.  Try using an `in` clause, instead.:

```
SELECT dscan.guid, dscan.drive, dscan.folder, dscan.filename, source.guid  
FROM source 
RIGHT JOIN dscan ON (
  dscan.guid in (source.guid & '_dtr', source.guid & '_dto', source.guid)
  AND dscan.guid LIKE '%" & Replace(strSearch_guid, "'", "''") & "%'  
  AND dscan.filename NOT LIKE '.[_]%'  
  AND dscan.drive = 'Z:')  
WHERE source.guid Is Null  
ORDER BY dscan.drive, dscan.guid
```

But, best yet, use your query execution plan to truly get a sense as to what the database engine is doing. You can then see where the real bottlenecks are, and possibly what indices you can add to speed up your query.

Comment: I had tried an IN but had the same result - the query takes so long to execute that the page won't load.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could re-order things. You could try:

- selecting from dscan first (I'm assuming the right join on dscan means you want all the rows from it). You may not even need a right join after that.
- re-ordering your ON clause, eg. put the comparisons most likely to fail first - to take advantage of short-circuiting. Put all the AND's first and the OR's last
- move some comparisons from the ON clause to the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your query:

```
 SELECT d.guid, 
        d.drive, 
        d.folder, 
        d.filename,
        src.guid
   FROM DSCAN d
   JOIN (SELECT s.quid,
                s.quid & '_dtr' AS DTR,
                s.quid & '_dto' AS DTO,
           FROM SOURCE s
          WHERE s.guid IS NOT NULL) src ON d.guid IN (s.quid, s.dtr, s.dto)
   WHERE d.guid LIKE '%' & REPLACE(strSearch_guid, "'", "''") & '%'
     AND d.filename NOT LIKE '.[_]%'  
     AND d.drive = 'Z:'
ORDER BY d.drive, d.guid
```

I assumed you had a type regarding the source.guid IS NULL in the OP - didn't make sense that you'd want only NULL source.guid records and then concatenate onto them.

This:

```
RIGHT JOIN dscan ON (source.guid & '_dtr' = dscan.guid OR 
                     source.guid & '_dto' = dscan.guid OR 
                     source.guid = dscan.guid)
```

...will only use the index, assuming one exists, on the guid column to create the values, **not** for comparison.  If you need to do this, it's best to construct them in an inline view or CTE/Subquery Factoring.

Comment: The source.guid IS NULL is in the right place in my query, since I only want records from the dscan table that don't match the source table. I had tried using IN in place of the ORs already, but with the same poor result.

Answer (score 0):

Now lets see your start off your select statement with the following:

*SELECT dscan.guid, dscan.drive, dscan.folder, dscan.filename, source.guid

FROM source 
RIGHT JOIN dscan ON*

and end it with this:

*WHERE source.guid Is Null

ORDER BY dscan.drive, dscan.guid*

So if I read this correctly your trying to read everything from the dscan table and anthing that matches for the source table.

**??What exactly links the two table if your looking for source.guid is null?  Because if source.guid is null why would you be doing a right like:**

**source 
RIGHT JOIN dscan ON (
  (source.guid & '_dtr' = dscan.guid OR source.guid & '_dto' = dscan.guid OR source.guid = dscan.guid)

  AND dscan.guid LIKE '%" & Replace(strSearch_guid, "'", "''") & "%'

  AND dscan.filename NOT LIKE '.[_]%'

  AND dscan.drive = 'Z:')**

Your query is taking a long time because it gets lost in the join. Your trying
to make it filter by too many things and filter by like '% blah blah %' does not 
help with speed.  Check to see if you have the proper indexs on the source table and dscan table.

Why is  **WHERE source.guid is NUll**  **You need source.guid to be something to match it with dscan.guide in the dscan table.**

Comment: The point of the source.guid is NULL is to identify records in the dscan table that don't have matches in the source table.

The other filters aren't the cause of the problem - it's definitely those ORs - and they are required to get the right results.